# Logo overlapping text when responding to screen sizes

Tags: css, position, viewport, styling, responsive

I'm pretty new to coding and need to pick some of your brains in order to fix this issue which is occurring on a holding page that I'm currently coding.

The company logo is positioned in the bottom corner and at certain screen size overlaps and interferes with the text (when you manually resize the browser window). I've used media queries so this doesn't happen on devises.

I'm not sure whats possible, but I always need the logo to be in the bottom right hand corner. But I'd like the logo to disappear from the screen when the logo starts interfere with the text , ideally I'd like the user to have to scroll down to see the logo at this point.

This the site in question http://embalmer-tiger-47168.bitballoon.com/

Heres My HTML

```
        <img class="logo--master" src="assets/images/logomark.png" alt="Proud Robinson Logo">

    </div>
```

Heres my CSS

```
.logos {
position: absolute;
bottom: 55px;
right: 55px;

}

.logo--master {
    width: 7em;

}
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need your logo to have a relative position to your text. You can use position:relative. After that if it still doesn't respond like you would like it to, you can position it in a div that as the same width as the page (width:100%) and you can use de margin of your logo to center it (usually margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; will work, but you might have to use %). Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioning an element takes it out of the normal flow of the page, so that other elements don't know it's there and will overlap. If you apply a right and bottom `margin` to `.container` that matches the size of the logo, the content in `.container` won't overlap. The logo is about `7em` tall/wide (per the width you gave it in css) and is 55px from the right/bottom, so a right/bottom margin of `calc(7em  + 55px)` on `.container` should leave room for the logo.

```
div.container {
    margin: 0 calc(7em + 55px) calc(7em + 55px) 0;
}
```